# how to add missing rows of time series data to panda dataframes in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, time-series, missing-data

I have a time series dataset of product given below:

```
date    product price   amount
11/17/2019  A   10  20
11/19/2019  A   15  20
11/24/2019  A   20  30
12/01/2019  C   40  50
12/05/2019  C   45  35
```

This data has a missing days ("MM/dd/YYYY") between the start and end date of data for each product. I am trying to fill missing date with zero rows and convert to previous table into a table given below:

```
date    product price   amount
11/17/2019  A   10  20
11/18/2019  A   0   0
11/19/2019  A   15  20
11/20/2019  A   0   0
11/21/2019  A   0   0
11/22/2019  A   0   0
11/23/2019  A   0   0
11/24/2019  A   20  30
12/01/2019  C   40  50
12/02/2019  C   0   0
12/03/2019  C   0   0
12/04/2019  C   0   0
12/05/2019  C   45  35
```

To get this conversion, I used the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data=pd.read_csv("test.txt", sep="\t", parse_dates=['date'])
data=data.set_index(["date", "product"])
start=data.first_valid_index()[0]
end=data.last_valid_index()[0]
df=data.set_index("date").reindex(pd.date_range(start,end, freq="1D"), fill_values=0)
```

However the code gives an error. Is there any way to get this conversion efficiently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If need add `0` for missing Datetimes for each `product` separately use custom function in [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by minimal and maximal datetime:

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.txt", sep="\t", parse_dates=['date'])

f = lambda x: x.reindex(pd.date_range(x.index.min(), 
                                      x.index.max(), name='date'), fill_value=0)
df = (df.set_index('date')
        .groupby('product')
        .apply(f)
        .drop('product', axis=1)
        .reset_index())
print (df)
   product       date  price  amount
0        A 2019-11-17     10      20
1        A 2019-11-18      0       0
2        A 2019-11-19     15      20
3        A 2019-11-20      0       0
4        A 2019-11-21      0       0
5        A 2019-11-22      0       0
6        A 2019-11-23      0       0
7        A 2019-11-24     20      30
8        C 2019-12-01     40      50
9        C 2019-12-02      0       0
10       C 2019-12-03      0       0
11       C 2019-12-04      0       0
12       C 2019-12-05     45      35
```

Comment: Make sure the dtype for 'date' is dt or you will get an error. Clearly above code deals with this by using parse_dates when reading in data. But if data is already in df use ```df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])```

Answer (score 0):

one option is to use the [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete.complete) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) to expose the missing rows per group:

```py
#pip install git+https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git
import pandas as pd
import janitor

# build the dates to be applied per group
dates = dict(date = lambda df: pd.date_range(df.min(), df.max(), freq='1D'))

df.complete(dates, by='product', sort = True).fillna(0, downcast='infer')

                   date product  price  amount
0   2019-11-17 00:00:00       A     10      20
1   2019-11-18 00:00:00       A      0       0
2   2019-11-19 00:00:00       A     15      20
3   2019-11-20 00:00:00       A      0       0
4   2019-11-21 00:00:00       A      0       0
5   2019-11-22 00:00:00       A      0       0
6   2019-11-23 00:00:00       A      0       0
7   2019-11-24 00:00:00       A     20      30
8   2019-12-01 00:00:00       C     40      50
9   2019-12-02 00:00:00       C      0       0
10  2019-12-03 00:00:00       C      0       0
11  2019-12-04 00:00:00       C      0       0
12  2019-12-05 00:00:00       C     45      35
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier method for this case:

```
#create the full date range, and then create a DataFrame with the range
#if needed, you can expand the range a bit using datetime.timedelta()
alldates=pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(data.index.min()-timedelta(1),data.index.max()+timedelta(4), freq="1D",name="newdate"))

#make 'newdate' the index, and you no longer need it as a column
alldates.index=alldates.newdate
alldates.drop(columns="newdate", inplace=True)

#now, join the tables, missing dates in the original table will be filled with NaN
data=alldates.join(data)
```